# Moq callbase for async methods doesn't work

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, callback, moq

I have class which is mocked but in some cases I need to run original method

```
public virtual async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(string userId)
{
    try
    {
        TrackChanges(userId);//sets some fields
        return await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogSaveValidationFailed(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

I have tried `CallBase = true`, but it don't work for `async` methods, also tried workaround with `CallBack`...

```
var db = new Mock<DbContext>();
db.CallBase = true;
db.Setup(x => x.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(1).Callback((string user) =>
{
    db.Object.SaveChanges(user);
});
```

...it returns value bud never call callback.
Everything works normal method but doesn't work with async. 
What can I do to make it work with Moq, or it's better just refactor a bit and move `TrackChanges` from async method to normal?

Comment: Is `IDbContext` is a class or interface? `CallBase` won't work on interfaces...

Comment: fixed code sample, it's a class

Comment: Why do you would you want to call the original method? Basically  `SaveChangesAsync` calls `SaveChanges` in a new `Task` so you can use the real `DbContext` instead of the fake one... One more thing how do you verify that the original `SaveChanges` wasn't called?

Comment: Could you explain "some cases I need to run original method"? It looks like you are combining unit- and integration tests .

Comment: yes i do that, mock all external parts, but i want to run all my code from end to end,

Comment: @OldFox... you helped solve the problem here... I was actually mocking the Interface! Thank you very much for the comment. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heh actually with db.CallBase = true it works, but it fails when there is also db.setup().callbase()

Answer (score 0):

I know that the documentation says you can do

> db.CallBase = true

but I have never used that approach myself. This is how I partially mock a class and it works good.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyClassTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task MyClass_ReturnsCorrectValues()
    {
        // Arrange
        var m = new Mock<MyClass>();
        m.Setup(x => x.IsKing())
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(true));
        m.Setup(x => x.IsQueen())
            .CallBase();

        // Act
        var isKing = await m.Object.IsKing();
        var isQueen = await m.Object.IsQueen();

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(isKing); // true
        Assert.IsFalse(isQueen); // false
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public virtual async Task<bool> IsKing()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(false);
    }

    public virtual async Task<bool> IsQueen()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(false);
    }
}
```